# How do you calculate phase from sin wave equation?

Tags: waves

So if a wave equation is $A \sin \left(k x - \omega t + \phi \right)$ then how can you calculate what the phase would be? From the graph, it is visible to see where the graph has shifted but just by numerical values how could you tell?

Answer (score 1):

For the equation you have assumed, the phase shifts by time but stays the same. So you could simply ignore the $\omega t$ for the sake of simplicity. Therefore, to be sure of the phase, you could check the derivative with respect to $x$ and the its relation to zero to determine its phase.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit? The phrase “the phase shifts by time but stays the same” is rather contradictory. How the derivative with respect to $x$ and its relation to zero can determine the phase? Could you elaborate on that a bit and maybe add some equations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the equation you present is **not** the wave equation but one of the many possible solutions to it.

The phase $\phi$ refers to the value of the solution at $t = 0$ for a distance from the source $x = 0$ (assuming the source is positioned at the origin or just that $x$ is the distance from the source).

So, all you have to do to find $\phi$ is to plug $t = 0$ and $x = 0$ and then use the inverse sine function to get

$$ \begin{split}
y \left(x, t \right) & =  A \sin \left(k x - \omega t + \phi \right) \implies y \left(0, 0 \right) =  A \sin \left(\phi \right) \implies\\
\implies \sin \left( \phi \right) & = \frac{y \left( 0, 0 \right)}{A} \implies \phi = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{y \left( 0, 0 \right)}{A} \right)
\end{split} \tag{1} \label{1} $$

You may notice that the amplitude $A$ is used as a normalisation factor here that will constrain the $\frac{y \left( x, t \right)}{A}$ term to the range $\left[ -1, 1 \right]$.

#### Update

Please note that for a position other than the location of the source ($x \neq 0$, that is) there will be an inherent initial phase $\phi_{x} \neq \phi$ for $t = 0$, due to the distance of the location from the source position. This phase will also depend on the wavelength (so the wavenumber too). To see that you can do

$$ y \left( x, 0 \right) = A \sin \left( k x - 0 + \phi \right) \implies y \left( x, 0 \right) = A \sin \left( k x + \phi \right) \implies y \left( x, 0 \right) = A \sin \left( \phi_{x} \right) \tag{2} \label{2} $$

where you have to notice that $\phi_{x} = k x + \phi$ is constant throughout time and can be regarded as the initial phase at the location $x$. You can again solve for it in the same way we did in *equation \eqref{1}* to get

$$ y \left( x, 0 \right) = A \sin \left( \phi_{x} \right) \implies \sin \left( \phi_{x} \right) = \frac{y \left( x, 0 \right)}{A} \implies \phi_{x} = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{y \left( x, 0 \right)}{A} \right) \tag{3} \label{3} $$